# How to import other js file in Django + Webpack + Vue2 + SFC

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, sfc

I am using Django and Webpack and Vue2. And wrote app.vue file as the SFC in Vue.
I import other js file (original library) in app.vue, But I got a error message from Chrome's console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'render' of undefined

.vue file can importing other js files? In that case, how to import other js files?

index.html

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <App></App>
</div>

{% render_bundle 'main' %}

</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './app.vue';
import routes from './routes';

Vue.config.devtools = true;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: __dirname,
    routes: routes,
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'App': App,
    },
    router: router,
});
```

app.vue

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from './lib/hello.js';
</script>
```

lib/hello.js

```
export default class Hello {

    world() {
        console.log('Hello, World!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your whole `app.vue`? Just tested it and it should work, but where's your template and component part of code?

Comment: I updated part of codes.